# jquery in a loop

Tags: jquery, loops

I have been assisted by the remarkable chaps and chapesses in this site to get this far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#join').click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "320px"
        }, 500, function () {
            $(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
        });
    })
    $('#joinClose').click(function () {
        $('#join').animate({
            height: "40px"
        }, 500, function () {
            $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        });
    });
});
```

My div grows from it's static height of 40px, to 320 upon click and sets overflow to visible - lovely.
however I have added a button to revert back. It sort of works, but as soon as it gets to it's normal size, it grows again! I am pretty new to coding - do I need a stop somewhere?!?!?!

thanks guys.

Comment: check out www.jsfiddle.net.  It's a really handy tool to use here in order to demonstrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: This happens because the .click listener of the #join element is triggered for some reason. And you forgot a ";" at line 6 ;)

Comment: Pete, is the #joinClose inside of the #join div? If so that could be part of the problem. You should post your html here as well (or in a JSFiddle).

Answer (score 4):

If `joinClose` is a child of `join`, you need to `stopPropagation` on `joinClose` to prevent it from propagating to `join`.

```
$('#joinClose').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
```